# UIImage.hidden is not working in iphone app

Tags: iphone, uiimageview

I have added a image in nib file and I kept it as hidden. I am running if statement and when condition is being true I am loading my next screen or nib file. My condition is being true and first time image is appearing and next screen is also loading well. Again I am being back with navbar to the same screen. My program is again running and condition is being true but image is not appearing there.

Here is the code of loading nib file

```
 Fave *bController = [[Fave alloc] initWithNibName:@"Fave" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:bController animated:YES];
    [bController release];
```

And here is my condition of image

```
if([tempPostTime doubleValue] > [prevFacebookMessageList doubleValue])
{

    NSLog(@" curr time %f  prev time %f", [tempPostTime doubleValue],[prevFacebookMessageList doubleValue]);
    updateImage.hidden=NO;

}
```

The above IF statement is running fine for first time and in second time is is also executing well but Image is not appearing on interface.

Please help me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to call that method when you return from the second screen to first and ensure the condition is met.

Comment: But IF statement is running well only image is not coming on interface.

Comment: I agree with @Deepak, you may not have connected the outlet.

Comment: I have connected with outlet and it is running well when I am first time on screen. IF condition is true Image is appearing.But problem is happening when I am coming from second screen to first screen.My second screen has tableview with navigation and I am being back from navigation.

Comment: Where do you use the 'if' condition? In 'viewWillAppear'?

Comment: Are you resetting the outlet somewhere? Try `NSLog(@"%@", updateImage);` within the `if` block.

Comment: @Developer If statement is in my custom function. That function is being called in time interval of 1 minute. in each 1 minute it is cheking for update and then Image will be appear if update occurs. @"Deepak" I did I am getting follwoing on my screen <UIImageView: 0x4e45710; frame = (8 1; 22 20); autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x4e3b310>> FIRST TIME it is printing this on console <UIImageView: 0x4e76560; frame = (8 1; 22 20); hidden = YES; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x4e76910>>

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your image is correctly configured in interface builder,

```
// Either show of hide the image
if([tempPostTime doubleValue] > [prevFacebookMessageList doubleValue])
{
    NSLog(@" curr time %f  prev time %f", [tempPostTime doubleValue],[prevFacebookMessageList doubleValue]);
    updateImage.hidden=NO;
} else {
    updateImage.hidden = YES;
}
```

If your first time through the if statement hides the image, it will remain hidden!

Answer (score 0):

The logs in the comments clearly indicate two different instances of `UIImageView`. You probably are reassigning `updateImage` sometime when you come back. You are losing the reference to the image view on screen so you are not updating it. Check your code for reassignments of `updateImage`.

Comment: I removed and I wrote this code in my IF statement        
        UIImageView* brickAnim = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Update_icon.gif"]]autorelease];
        brickAnim.frame =CGRectMake(291, 50, 22, 20); But same problem is occuring.
        [self.view addSubview:brickAnim];

Comment: @Ajay_Kumar Can you explain the use case a bit?